# How to move Skrollr elements diagonally

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

Hello I am completely new to js and skrollr/parallax and I need to move four images diagonally towards the center and fade into a new image. I have been scouring the web for about a day and a half to no avail. Nor have any tutorials/documentation been very helpful. I will include a very crude photoshop image to give you guys a good idea of what I need to do. Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
http://www.yournetpass.com/ben/pics/skrollr.jpg

Comment: First step: Read what StackOverflow is and how to use it.